# NullPointerException when replacing fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmentmanager

**This is not a duplicate!** I've read the other question, but the answers it provided didn't work (I've just declared my object when I reference it; there's no way it's null) I'm not sure how stackoverflow works yet, but I'd hate to see this locked over a misunderstanding.

After hours of googling and combing through my code I'm baffled.

I'm attempting to replace one fragment (ScriptsFragment) with another fragment (ScenesFragment) within ScriptFragment's code. When fragment manager tries to replace, it throws the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alecdb.lineburner/com.alecdb.lineburner.ScriptsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Any help would be greatly appreciated-- I'm completely stumped.

Here's the part that should replace ScriptFragment with SceneFragment:

```
@Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container2,new ScenesFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }`
```

And here's SceneFragment (Minus two methods which I've tested elsewhere) :

```
public class ScenesFragment extends Fragment {
public List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
public SQLiteDatabase newDB;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement_scenes, container, false);

    listView = new ListView(null);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Here's my MainActivity (ScriptsActivity) which adds ScriptFragment initially:

```
package com.alecdb.lineburner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class ScriptsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scripts);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container,new ScriptsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scripts, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here's the Activity's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
                                            >
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    class="com.alecdb.lineburner.ScriptsFragment">

</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
    class="com.alecdb.lineburner.ScenesFragment">

</FrameLayout>
```

And SceneFragment's XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.alecdb.lineburner.ScenesFragment"
            >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TESTING TESTING TESTING!!!!"/>
```

And lastly, ScriptFragment's XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/scripts_fragment"
                tools:context="com.alecdb.lineburner.ScriptsFragment"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scripts">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ScriptsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:authorities="com.alecdb.lineburner.app"
        android:name="com.alecdb.lineburner.data.LineBurnerProvider"
        />
</application>
```

Thanks again,

Alec Burns

P.S. This is my first post on StackOverflow. Please let me know if I've done something wrong.

Comment: please post activity XML too

Comment: 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on which line is this error

Comment: @Dex I added the XML.

Comment: @VivekMishra I'm not certain which line; I pasted the entire error on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VGWLXpAk)

Comment: then probably this line can be the cause `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scripts, menu);` Comment this line and then check

Comment: @VivekMishra I tried commenting out that line (in ScriptsActivity, in the onCreateOptionsMenu method) but the exception still throws like normal.

Comment: What's at Scene Fragment line no 47

Comment: "there's no way it's null" -> If you get a NPE the object *is* `null`.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak You're right; turns out a different object than I was thinking was null was null. I was focusing on the fragment itself, when it was actually a listview inside the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **ScenesFragment**. you didn't declare the listview. that causes the exception and all.

Comment: In that case it will give `ActivityNotFoundException`  not `NullPointerException`

Comment: I have experienced this case of exception for not declaring the activity in the Manifest file.

Comment: you must be having both exception in your case but if activity is not decalred in manifest then it will give ActivityNotFoundException instead of NullPointer

Comment: Im not talking about the NullPointer exception. actually i have mentioned the exception also in my answer.

Comment: Replace with RunTimeException in place of NullPointerException in my comments

Comment: What I mean to say is if Activity is missing from manifest then it will give  ActivityNotFoundException not any other

Comment: I'll add my manifest above; It appears to be declared, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: In **ScenesFragment** you didn't declare the listview.

Comment: @SteMusicLuvr That's it!! Thank you-- I can't believe I didn't notice that immediately... I guess I was so focused on the fragment transition that I didn't check the fragment. Add that as an answer and I'll "Accept" it.